# Treating an int as an address/pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, memory-address

I have a C function that returns an int that represents the base address of some block in memory. If I wanted to treat the value of that int as an address (so that I could treat it as an array or otherwise traverse the area in memory it points to) what syntax would I use?

Comment: You can't.  `int`s and pointers are not the same size.  Your function must be changed to return an actual pointer.

Comment: On plenty of machines `int`s and pointers are the same size.

Comment: As SLacks stated, you should be returning an actual pointer from the function. If for some reason that's not possible, use `size_t` instead.

Comment: @Tim Cooper - That's no more guaranteed to work than `int`. Recommending anything other than `intptr_t` is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Trent - "It works on _my_ machine..."

Comment: @Chris Lutz, I made the assumption that the return type could not be modified, I do not advocate dependency on implementation defined details.

Comment: @Chris: or the smart version, "I have documented the constraints that your C implementation must meet in order for it to work on your machine". Ideally you also ensure that the code doesn't compile otherwise, a crude first attempt in this case being to statically assert `sizeof(int) >= sizeof(void*)`, although that's not perfect. Note that `intptr_t` is an *optional* type, so using it is the same "works on my machine" pattern, although a much more benign instance of it.

Comment: @Trent, 64-bit operating systems are over 30% of the desktop market today.  Rough departure from 15 years of 32-bit code: sizeof(int) != sizeof(void*).  An obvious fact to programmers that use a VM, C programmers are a bit slow that catch that up.  Ironic, isn't it?

Comment: @Hans: if the code is running on such an implementation, then a function can't return an int that represents an address. The questioner's code does return an int that represents an address. Ergo, the questioner's code is not running on any such machine (and is not portable) ;-) C isn't slow to catch up, it's already there and never has said that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(void*)`. Possibly though the questioner or whichever colleague wrote that function, needs to get up to speed.

Comment: @Hans, perhaps 30% of desktop market is 64-bit, but the entire desktop market size pales to the number of 8, 16, and 32-bit embedded machines out there.  Again, I do not advocate relying on implementation defined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `int`s and pointers are the same size on your machine a simple cast should work.

For example:

```
int function_that_returns_address();
...
char * p = (char *) function_that_returns_address();
p[0] = 'H';
p[1] = 'i';
p[2] = 0;
```

Comment: Right but the compiler complains if I try to dereference a dereferenced value. i.e. if i did int *x = (int *)address; then I would want the value at *x, not x, resulting in something like (*x)[i] or **x, which the compiler would whine about.

Comment: @Zach, that is not how you would access any pointer, I have added an example to show how to access it correctly.  In your example you are dereferencing the pointer twice (not sure why you think you need to do that)

Comment: Additionally the function returns the address as an int, so *p would give the address as its value, and I want to dereference the value at its address value --> the values at address *p

Comment: Perhaps I was too confused to see that what you're doing actually does resolve my problem.

Comment: @Zach, in my example `p` contains the address that was returned by the function (not `*p` as you claim).  To access the memory that is pointed to by `p` you dereference it: either `*p` or `p[index]`.

Comment: +1, fortunately the answer is the same with a different integer type. Figuring out whether any suitable integer type exists on a given C implementation is another question, I think.